# Spyder reports invalid alias when running any script

Tags: python, spyder

I can't tell why this is happening but it seems to have started when I updated (everything - conda update --all). It had been about 1 year since I last had updated. Something must have changed.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Mar  3 11:25:22 2019

@author: pitosalas
"""

print("hello")
```

And here is the output from pressing the green triangle in spyder:

```
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('/Users/pitosalas/Box Sync/datawork/2019Resubmit/deleteme.py', wdir='/Users/pitosalas/Box Sync/datawork/2019Resubmit')
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name clear can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name more can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name less can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
ERROR:root:Invalid alias: The name man can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
hello
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The answer provided by @yazaemon is correct: this problem was introduced by IPython **7.3.0**. Until it's fixed by the IPython guys, please downgrade to 7.2.0 (as suggested below too).

Comment: Getting this same problem with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: This problem is still there in IPython 7.6.1. Why hasn't it been removed yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11646), IPython 7.7.0 sorted out this problem. I can confirm updating to 7.7.0 worked for me (conda 4.7.10 on Ubuntu 18.04, Spyder 3.3.6).

Answer (score 6):

I met same situation today, and I checked as following.
`conda create -n testenv python spyder ipython=7.3`
The issue happen.

`conda create -n testenv python spyder ipython=7.2.0`
In this environment, it doesn't happen.

I recommend you to rebuild your environment using ipython7.2.0 or downgrade with this:

```
conda install ipython=7.2.0
```

Comment: Worked for me, for those lazy to search:

`pip install update ipython==7.2.0`

And reinstall the kernel

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=ipy_kernel_name`

Answer (score 2):

The root cause can be traced down to [this commit](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11528/commits/05bfcf38788982320d54550b3aeb0f5853aedb7f) to ipython. Downgrading to ipython=7.2.0 certainly helps. Hope this can be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

conda install ipython=7.2.0  worked for me.  ipython 7.3.0 was the culprit.